# Node.js, Socket.io and RabbitMQ to handle concurrent connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a push notification system using Node.js, Socket.io and RabbitMQ.

The flow of my system is as follows:

1. RabbitMQ is published through a PHP script with fan-out exchange type.
2. Node.js server is subscribed to a queue connected through the same exhange as created in step 1.
3. When a client connects to node.js server, it sends a unique id through an event.
4. The unique id sent in step 3 is then compared with the message that is received from the queue subscribed in step 2.
5. If the condition in step 4 returns true, the entire message from the queue is then emitted to a client with that unique id. So only the specific client receives the desired message and not to all the clients connected.

So is it feasible to loop through all the unique ids of all the connected clients? So in this case every message consumed from the queue will be compared with all the connected clients.

I am expecting 50 to 60 thousand connections, so is it actually feasible to loop these many connections?

Or will it be feasible to create 50 to 60 thousand Queues binded to one exchange?

Or Should I simply broadcast the message to all the clients and comparison will be handled at client side?

Are these the only solutions or there could be some different implementation to handle this.